# How to get iPhone mute setting programmatically ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, iphone-5

My app wants to know the current mute setting of iPhone. Is there a way to achieve this? I see some solutions in google, but they don't work on my iPhone5. Any example codes or open source solutions?

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know you can't access the  volume apis in your application. Those are private apis . If you are access theses api by any way then also it tends to reject your application by apple .

Answer (score -2):

This is how you change the volume with public api:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:currentVolume];
```

But to mute it I don't think there really is a public API.